# Using a static member from a derived class instead of the base class

Tags: c++, static, method-resolution-order

As above, I'm trying to create a static variable name called increment_rate that has a default value of 1.05 for all Employee class.

However, the Developer class (derived from Employee class) enjoys a default increment_rate of 1.10 instead (yay to programmers).

In the Employee class, I have a public method called apply_incr(). Whenever I call it, standard Employees (such as the base class Employee, or other sub-classes such as Clerk or Janitor) only enjoys a standard increment_rate of 1.05, while sub-class Developer should automatically enjoy 1.10.

In python, the method resolution order will automatically choose the derived-class's increment_rate by default IF both the base class and the derived class has the variable increment_rate.
However in C++, how would I implement such a similar functionality such that it will automatically apply 1.10 for developers, while everyone else only get 1.05?

Because all Clerk or all Janitor or all Employee has the same rate of 1.05, that's why I chose to use a static member that is used class wide, instead of a normal member that is unique to each instances of the class.

Thanks!

Comment: C++ is not Python, if it were Python it wouldn't be called C++. In C++ you cannot have a static variable that dynamically resolves to the right class. You need to make a virtual function that returns the value you want, and use it whenever you would use a variable in Python. You will need to override the function in each derived class. The function may fetch the value from a static variable, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why there is a need for a static variable.. Assuming the `apply_incr()` is not static, you could very well have it like this:

```
class Employee {

public:
    virtual double getIncrementRate() const { return 1.05; }
}

class Developer : Employee {

public:
    virtual double getIncrementRate() const override { return 1.10; }
}
```

Comment: Note: When you explicitly say `override` (good), also saying `virtual` is just redundant noise. Just `double getIncrementRate() const override { return 1.10; }` should be sufficient.

Comment: @JesperJuhl while I do agree with the principle, that all boils down to the coding convention of the projects you work on.

Comment: Thanks AlexG! I shall try it out immediately. The reason why I thought of static variable was mainly because I wanted to use a variable that is standardised throughout all instances of that same class (hence my brain started thinking only in that direction).  Never did I think of using a method to return a specific value instead. On that line, I was also not aware of the virtual function nor usage of const (and override), so I shall go learn up on those keywords/methods as well. Thanks once again!

Comment: Thanks Jesper Juhl, I'll note the possibility that virtual is optional. Hopefully with some more learning and experimenting, I will be able to see which is more suitable for what I want to do in time to come. Thanks!